# Simple Search Plugin Does Not Perform Search

Tags: plugin-development, search

Created a very simple plugin to display a custom search form. No errors, but not performing search. I may be over my head and leaving out one or many requirements.

My plugin code:

```
/**
 * Begin Shortcode.
 */
function divilicious_micro_search($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('color' => 'teal'), $atts));

   return '<div id="dlms">
            <form role="search" method="get" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '"  class="dlms">
              <input type="search" class="dlms-search-input" placeholder="'.esc_attr__('Search...','dlms').'" value="'.get_search_query().'" name="s" title="Search for:" >
              '.get_search_query().'
              <button style="background:'.$color.'" type="submit">
                <span class="fontawesome-search"></span>
              </button>
            </form>
        </div>';
}

add_shortcode('dl-micro-search', 'divilicious_micro_search');
```

Am I missing something that will give me a fighting chance or shall I give up?

Comment: Highlight your code in editor and then click the `{}` sign above the editor. Or simply indent each line with 4 spaces. This will all display your code in a code block

Comment: Works for me. Please try to describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Here is my test page. Click the orange icon to open, enter your search term and see what happens (or not).
http://divilicious.com/a-micro-search-plugin-shortcode-test-page/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't executing the shortcode. The raw text is simply being `echo`ed to the page. I don't know why, but I assume you've just written something like `[ dl-micro-search color="hex or named color" ]` into the source when you should have `echo do_shortcode('[ dl-micro-search color="hex or named color" ]');` instead.

Comment: I'll give that a try!